# XAML expert design

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am a small ISV. 2 developers.
I have an existing application for Windows that we sale. 
I would like to rewrite the UI using WPF and maybe even create a Silverlight version on the web.
I have 20 years experience, and I learn things fast.
I am sure I could learn XAML, WPF, and Silverlight. However, I am wondering if I should write the initial UI.
I have listened to all of the talk about the value of a true designer on a project. I believe most of what I have heard. So, I want to find a XAML expert designer to design my new UI and write all of my initial XAML.

How do I find this person?
What do I look for in this person?
Should I request a fixed price contract or is an hourly rate better?
Should I offer a percent of sales as payment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a typical WPF or Silverlight development there are 3 major development processes involved based on the skill set needed. And the % across each one is the approximate time for each.

1. Graphic Design and Information Architect - 15% -20%

   - PhotoShop / Illustrator/ Fireworks / Expression Design skills
   - Skills to analyse users, optimize the UI and present in a beautiful way
2. Development [ *precisely UX Development*] - 50 - 60%

   - Raw XAML development
   - ViewModel code development (MVVM & C#)
   - Custom/User control development
   - Mainly work with Visual Studio
3. XAML Integration [a skill-set who has knowledge both in Design and Development] 15-30%

   - Define the User interactions with the deisgner (1)
   - Convert Graphic design to XAML assets
   - Style/Template the controls
   - Storyboard the animations and create effects
   - Mainly uses Expression Blend and familiar with Illustrator/Photoshop/Expression Design or other design tools

You can start building the application (Step 2) when you get a rough idea about the design strategy and finish the full application in a look less way consuming all your Database/Web service etc. Graphic Design and XAML Integration can come little later and go parallel to the WPF development.

It may be hard to find people having skills on (1) and (3) together since XAML is relatively new .  And I am not sure about how to find a good Integrator. But you can surely find thousands of good designers/design shops around. And most of the Design tools will convert/export the design assets to XAML. But for a better UX you need an expert integrator.

- A good article to read - [The New Iteration](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/thenewiteration.aspx)
- It is also good to understand Model-View-ViewModel pattern to build Step (2) properly-[WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Note: If you are targeting both Silverlight and WPF, it is good you make Async webservices and let both  WPF and SL consume that as the Data layer. And check Prism and other MVVM implementations which makes the WPF to Silverlgiht port easy